# Grep from a doubly-gzipped file

Tags: grep, gzip

I have a file that is gzipped twice:

> test.gz.gz

How do I grep something from the file above? I don't want to unzip it.

Comment: why are you even bothering to double-gzip a file?  even if there is any benefit to be gained, you would still get even better compression using a better compression format like `xz`.

Comment: This file was sent to me by a client. >,>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may also

```
$ zcat test.gz.gz | zgrep "whatever"
```

`zcat` and `zgrep` works like `cat` and `grep` but on compressed data streams.

Comment: FWIW, `zcat` is just a wrapper that calls `gzip -dc` and `zgrep` is a more complicated wrapper around `gzip -cdfq | grep`

Answer (score 1):

Use two gzip's in a pipeline
e.g

```
gzip -dc test.gz.gz | gzip -dc | grep "search string"
```

The `-dc` flags mean "decompress to output", rather than creating the uncompressed file.